# “What” or “where” is his standing

Tags: word-choice

> *What* is his standing in the community?
>   *Where* is his standing in the community?

Which one is better? What if *community* is replaced by *competition*?

Comment: Personally, it sounds unnatural to ask of someone's social standing to me.

Comment: "Where is his standing..." doesn't sound natural to me in any of these contexts.

Comment: @Luke: What do you mean with "unnatural". Pheraps something related to English grammar and usage?

Comment: Less the grammar, it just seems rude.

Answer (score 5):

As a noun, *[standing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/standing#Noun)* has senses 
"Position or reputation in society or a profession" and
"The position of a team in a league or of a player in a list", among others.  Thus, your first form ("What is his standing in the community?") asks about the position of a person in a community.  The second form ("Where is his standing in the community?") somewhat redundantly and nonsensically asks about the location of a position.  The question is not one of grammar, but of sense.

The same applies if word *community* is replaced by *competition*.  However, while one *can* ask  "What is his standing in the competition?", I'd expect to hear more commonly "How does he stand in the competition?", or similar, when *stand* or *standing* is used.

Answer (score 0):

All four sentences can be more clearly expressed.

> What is his standing in the community? -> What is his position...?

or

> What is his standing in the community? -> What is his reputation...?

These use clearer word choices.  The original sentence implies both the others and is thereby in itself less definite.

> What is his standing in the competition? -> What is his ranking...?

Both mean the same thing; the latter is less ambiguous.

> Where is his standing in the community? -> *Confusing.*

Q: What is a "standing"?  It is not clear that either position or reputation is intended.

> Where is his standing in the competition? (and "Where does he stand in the competition?") -> *Ambiguous.*

Either version works, actually.  But to say: "What is his ranking...?" would express the thought much more clearly.  (Of these two, the latter is better but could also mean: "Where should he stand to await his turn in the competition?")

Also good:

> Where does he stand in the rankings?